# mate-terminal: trigger profile on command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-mate

When I start an ssh session I want some constant on screen signal, such as a color change, that reminds me that this session is not local. I keep a lot of terminals open and I too often don't notice what host a session is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, because `ssh` sets some enviroment variables. I logged in via `ssh local host`:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 52602 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/5
SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 52602 127.0.0.1 22
```

Then, in your `~/.bashrc` on the target, you can:

```
if [[ \! -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]] ; then
# change terminal colors 30=black text, 41=red background     
    echo '^[[30;41m'
fi
```

If you must do it on the source system,

```
alias redssh="echo '^[[30;41m';ssh"
```

The `clear` command will reset the colors.

See http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#colors for more color choices.

Comment: This is great. Except how do I reset the mate-terminal profile? I put  ````mate-terminal --profile alternate````  under your condition and boy oh boy was that the wrong thing to do!

Comment: "wrong thing to do"? What does this mean?

Comment: It meant that every time .bashrc was processed it opened a new mate-terminal session which processed .bashrc which opened a new mate-terminal session which eventually locked the system. I had to reboot and open a virtual console to edit the bashrc.

Comment: I have changed my question to highlight the requirement rather than the implementation.